# Find Subversion working copies with a given repository hostname

Tags: windows, http, svn

The host name for our Subversion server has changed and I have many working copies scattered around under certain directory tree. Can you think of some way to at least find them? I don't mind issuing the relocate command manually, but I'm having a hard time figuring out where all the working copies are and which ones are poiting to the decomissioned server. A search for the old host name within a text editor could only find a small percentage of the working copies, possibly because the value is stored in a database.

I could write a short script if necessary, if I just knew what to find.

Any idea?

<sub>*Context: our services use machine names (`https://winsrv01.example.com/` instead of `https://svn.example.com/`). New hardware/VM pops in, paths change. Gotta live with that.*</sub>

Comment: I might be wrong, but a working copy contains a hidden .svn folder, there might be many of them since there is one in each sub folder. What about searching for folders with an .svn sub folder?

Comment: @kennyzx That's right, but I then need to filter out by repository host name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually wrote a custom script that searches for `.svn` folders and then issues a `svn info` command on each:

```
svn info "C:\Projects\Client Foo\Site Bar\stagging" --show-item repos-root-url
```

To write a really robust solution you need to take care of endless stuff (such as old working copies that need upgrading) but it's fine for a quick hack.